# Installing 18.04 from USB gives blur screen

Tags: system-installation, screen

When I try Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB stick without installing, everything is fine. According to Ubuntu screen properties are 1680x1050 ATI RV515. I'm working on a Dell Optiplex 740.

When I install it (clean install), the installation completes normally. But after reboot the starting screen is a blur. Can't see anything. Therefore I can't log in and can't change stettings.

A few years ago I've installed version 14 before without a problem. What can I do?

Thx!

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is supported until April 2019. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is supported until April 2021. Please try them. Notice that 14.04 LTS is the last LTS version, where you can use proprietary ATI/AMD/Radeon drivers. In 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS you should let the system use the built-in linux radeon driver. -- I am not sure, but it may help with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Comment: Thank you! How can i change the grub loader that is installed on my pc? When i start Ubuntu from usb the modification to grub are not stored on the pc. And i can t started the installed Ubuntu version.

Comment: It is described in the link in my previous comment (marked red) and links from that link. Please read it and try. Tell me if you need more details.

Comment: I used: sudo gedit /etc/default/grub   After  sudo update-grub I get: /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'  I'm Googling this error but it gets a bit complicated.  Still working on it.

Comment: 1. Use `sudo -H` with GUI programs, so `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` or  `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (text mode editor `nano`). Otherwise you may damage the settings in your home directory; 2. `cow` indicates that you are running Ubuntu live, 'Try Ubuntu'. Is this {correct/what you want/the current stage}?

Comment: I'm running a dual boot system. On 1 partition I'd installed Ubuntu. 14.00 I decide to go for a fresh install from USB. The installation seem to go fine. But when I rebooted I got an very artistic blur screen. So now I'm running from the USB stick the Ubuntu live version and trying this way to update the Grub file on my HDD. I don't understand why the live version is running fine and the installed version ism' t. I'm still a beginner as you will have noticed. Think next step is to mount /dev/sda6 somehow  before I can run sudo update-grub command?

Comment: See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) for installing/repairing grub. [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is one of the suggested alternatives, and you may find it easier than the other alternatives.

Comment: Sorry Sudodus, I'm not allowed to use the chat.  I've tried Boot-Repair option. Installed it in the live version. No errors. But after reboot with the normal Ubuntu version the blur screen persists. I think this is getting to complicated for me.  I can change Grub but not update it on HDD so the old Grub is used to reboot.

Comment: Maybe Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will work better for you, It will be supported until April 2021, and it is well debugged and polished by now. -- If you start your comment with @sudodus, I will be notified and will see your comment sooner.

Comment: @sudodus I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 and this works fine. Than I upgraded the system from 16.04 to 18.04 and the problem reoccurs. I finally decided to go for Linux Mint 18.3. The installation was oke. One hour later I see there is an update to Linux Mint 19... but that is based on Ubuntu 18.04 so maybe upgrading isn't a good idea.

Comment: I would recommend that you re-install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or stay with Linux Mint 18.3 and avoid upgrading (as long as it is supported).